# Code Coverage: None

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Good day please can you kindly assist me with my test class. I am not getting any coverage and am confused. Please find below my controller and test class:

**I have VF page name CIF**

**Apex Controller**

```
public class MYController
{
public Lead leadDetail 
{get;set;}
public Id leadId
{get;set;}
 public string businessDocName 
{get;set;}

public Blob documentBody 
{get;set;} 

public string idCardName 
{get;set;}

public Blob idCardBody 
{get;set;} 

public MYController(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr)
{
   leadId = ctlr.getRecord().Id;     
}

public PageReference UpdateRecord(){

    leadDetail = [SELECT lastname,  Account_Name__c, Account_Number__c, Account_Type__c, dat__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: leadId];

    PageReference pgRef;
    if((documentBody != null && businessDocName != null)||(idCardBody != null && idCardName != null))
    {
        Attachment businessDocument  = new Attachment();
        Attachment idDocument  = new Attachment();
         if(documentBody != null && businessDocName != null)
        {
            businessDocument.Body = documentBody;
            businessDocument.Name = businessDocName;
            businessDocument.ParentId = leadId;
            try
            {
                if(idCardBody != null && idCardName != null)
                { 
                    idDocument.Body = idCardBody;
                    idDocument.Name = idCardName;
                    idDocument.ParentId = leadId;
                }
                insert businessDocument;
                insert idDocument;
            }catch(DMLException e)
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
                    return null;
            }
        }
        pgRef = new PageReference('http://MYCOMP.thankyou');
        pgRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pgRef;
    }   
    return null;
}    
}
```

**Unit Test Case**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
Public class TestMYController {
Static TestMethod void TestMYController ()
{  
    //define a page reference to scope the visual force page 
    PageReference pageRef = Page.CIF;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
    MYController controller = new MYController();

    //create a new Lead record then insert data.......
      Lead newLead= new Lead
        (
            Lastname = 'MYCOMP SHARED SERVICES',
            Company = 'MYCOMP',
            Account_Name__c = '23AugTestCase',
            Account_Number__c = '23082016',
            Account_Type__c = 'TestCase23Aug',
            dat__c = date.today()
        ); 
    //controller.leadDetail = newLead;
    //insert data into the record....
    insert newLead;
    system.debug('88888'+ newLead.Account_Name__c);

    //test the update implementation
    newLead.Account_Name__c ='Sales';
    update newLead;
    system.debug('88888'+ newLead.Account_Name__c);

    // Verify that the field was updated in the database.
    Lead updatedLead = [SELECT Account_Name__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :newLead.Id];
    System.assertEquals('Sales', updatedLead.Account_Name__c);

    //instantiate then read the methods from the ctrller....
    Test.startTest();
    List<Lead> leadData=[SELECT lastname, Company, Account_Name__c, Account_Number__c, Account_Type__c, dat__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: newLead.id];
        System.debug(leadData.size());
        System.assertEquals(1, leadData.size());
    update newLead;

    Attachment identityDoc= new Attachment();     
        identityDoc.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob idBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        identityDoc.body = idBlob;
        identityDoc.parentId=newLead.id;
        insert identityDoc;

    List<Attachment> IdAttachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:newLead.id limit 1];
        System.debug(IdAttachments.size());
        System.assertEquals(1, IdAttachments.size()); 


    Attachment bizDoc= new Attachment();     
        bizDoc.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
        Blob bizBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        bizDoc.body=bizBlob;
        bizDoc.parentId=newLead.id;
        insert bizDoc;

    List<Attachment> BIZattachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:newLead.id limit 1];
        System.assertEquals(1, BizAttachments.size());

    Test.stopTest(); 
    System.debug('****'+newLead.id);
}
}
```

Thank you very much for the assistance

Comment: you need to call UpdateRecord method inside your test class.

Comment: thanks for your response @Himashu, please can you edit as I am a bit lost

Comment: please go through https://trailhead.salesforce.com//en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

Comment: thanks a lot will go through the trail head, thanks for the link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialise your controller with your record:

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(newLead);
MYController myExt = new MYController(sc);
```

And as @Himashu proposed, you have to call your method:

```
Test.startTest();
myExt.UpdateRecord();
PageReference pageRef = myExt.autoRun();
Test.stopTest();
```

You can check that pagereference is returing some value by:

```
System.assertNotEquals(null,pageRef);
```

I've found very helpful [VisualForce in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) (see page 51)

Comment: And...does that a `Unit Test` make? You should mention testing best practices as this advice will just lead OP to **smoke testing**.

Comment: thank you for the assistance and sharing the book i really appreciate it...